# pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file jkpbne): Font jkpbne at 600 not found

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error

I'm running the error :

> pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file jkpbne): Font jkpbne at 600 not found

In my latex file, I already added

```
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
```

I'm using MikTex 2.9 and sublime 3 and here is the output of my log file:
https://pastebin.com/PZd571Wz

Comment: Your installation seems to be incomplete as regards to `kpfonts`. Anyway, you should not load both `lmodern` and `kpfonts`.

Comment: Try if it works if you renew the font maps (MiKTeX console, user mode, menu tasks).

Comment: If I comment %\usepackage{kpfonts}, I get now :
 LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/bx/sc' undefined(Font)              using `T1/lmss/bx/n' instead on input line 36.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems that my packages are up to date

Comment: It didn't suggest to update the packages but to renew the font map files, there is an entry in the tasks menu for this.

Comment: it worked!
Thanks a lot! :)